# How to call function on object coming from Hash-table value in c#

Tags: c#

I have a Hash-table that contain different objects. Now i want to call a function (StartEvaluation) on each object when i traverse through the Hash-table using for loop (all object have same function). i have try to cast object on run time and i was not able to. can someone explain me how to do it?

```
Hashtable EvaluationObjects = new Hashtable();
// Location Evaluation
LocationEvaluation le = new LocationEvaluation();

// Asset Evaluation
AssetEvaluation ae = new AssetEvaluation();

// Point Evaluation
PointEvaluation pe = new PointEvaluation();

EvaluationObjects.Add("LocationEvaluation", le);
EvaluationObjects.Add("AssetEvaluation", ae);
EvaluationObjects.Add("PointEvaluation", pe);
```

// calling function

```
void objectProcessTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e,string objectType,string message)
    {
        System.Timers.Timer tm = (System.Timers.Timer)sender;
        tm.Stop();

        var obj = EvaluationObjects[objectType];
        var s = obj.GetType();


        object obj =(object)EvaluationObjects[objectType];
        //MethodInfo method = typeof(obj).GetMethod("GenericMethod");
        //MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(myType);
        //generic.Invoke(this, null);

    }
```

Comment: Use `Dicrtionary<TKey, TValue>` in modern C#...

Comment: issue is still same. to call the SetEvaluation function i have to cast the Object which come from the TValue of the dictionary right ?
for now i have use this, but would like to know  if that can be done easily 
`switch (objectType)
 {
case "AssetEvaluation":
var obj_asset = (AssetEvaluation)EvaluationObjects[objectType];
obj_asset.StartEvaluation();
break;
case "LocationEvaluation":
var obj_location = (LocationEvaluation)EvaluationObjects[objectType];
obj_location.StartEvaluation();break;
}   `

Comment: Do you realise that you declare the variable `obj` twice in the example code?

Comment: The code also stinks with a bad design. What is the greater goal you want to accomplish?

Comment: second obj declaration is a mistake and it should be commented (i did some r n d). there can be many class that have StartEvaluation, so wanted to not to re-code same code part many places. so, want to call different objects's function robustly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create an interface (or base class), then have a Dictionary storing objects implementing that interface, like in this example:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

interface IEvaluation {
    void StartEvaluation();
}

class LocationEvaluation : IEvaluation {
    public void StartEvaluation() {
        // do something...
    }
}

class AssetEvaluation : IEvaluation {
    public void StartEvaluation() {
        // do something...
    }
}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {

        // fill dictionary with IEvaluation objects
        Dictionary<string, IEvaluation> evaluations = new Dictionary<string, IEvaluation>();
        evaluations["LocationEvaluation"] = new LocationEvaluation();
        evaluations["AssetEvaluation"] = new AssetEvaluation();

        // get an object from the dictionary and call the function on it
        IEvaluation evaluation = evaluations["AssetEvaluation"];
        evaluation.StartEvaluation();
    }
}
```